# dropdown list dinamico e retorno de imagem da bd não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework

`Dropdown` list dinâmico e retorno de imagem da base de dados não funciona depois da aplicação ser publicado no IIS. Ao Inspecionar através da browser tive o seguinte erro:

> Erro HTTP 404.0 - Not Found (com seguinte request:    http://localhost:80/funcionario/Concelho/List/1)

para imagem tive o seguinte através de Inspeção:

> Erro HTTP 404.0 - Not Found (com seguinte request:    http://localhost:80/funcionario/RetrieveImage/3

View create :

```
 $(function () {

        $("#Ilha").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/funcionario/Concelho/List/" + $("#Ilha > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                var items = "<option>--Selecione--</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, concelho) {
                    items += '<option value="' + concelho.Value + '">' + concelho.Text + '</option>';
                });
                $("#Concelho").html(items);
            });
        });
   });
```

no meu `routeconfig` criei Url:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
         "SelectConcelho",
         url: "Soldado/Concelho/List/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Soldado", action = "SelectConcelho", id = "" }
     );.....
```

e no *controller* fica o método:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SelectConcelho(String id)
    {
        SITMSEntities conetContext = new SITMSEntities();
        int ids;
        List<SelectListItem> ConcelhoNome = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            ids = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            List<Concelho> Concelhos = conetContext.Concelho.Where(s => s.Numero_ilha == ids).ToList();
            Concelhos.ForEach(s =>
            {
                ConcelhoNome.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s.Nome, Value = s.Numero.ToString() });

            }
                );

        }
        return Json(ConcelhoNome, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

[Authorize] 
public ActionResult RetrieveImage(int id) { 
    byte[] cover = GetImageFromDataBase(id); 
    if (cover != null) { 
        return File(cover, "image/jpg"); 
    } else { 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

e na `view` tenho:

```
<img src="/funcionario/RetrieveImage/ @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Numero)" alt="" height=80 width=80 />
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código de `RetrieveImage` na sua pergunta?

Comment: no controller:[Authorize]
        public ActionResult RetrieveImage(int id)
        {
            byte[] cover = GetImageFromDataBase(id);
            if (cover != null)
            {
                return File(cover, "image/jpg");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }  e na view tenho:<img src="/funcionario/RetrieveImage/ @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Numero)" alt="" height=80 width=80 />

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda na Organização do post Cigano. Este é o meu primeiro Post aqui.

Comment: Cadê a rota *Default* no `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: na url acima na routeconfig ó corecto e url: "funcionario/Concelho/List/{id}", e o controller e funcionario não soldado

Comment: Você pode editar sua pergunta clicando em "editar", logo abaixo do corpo da pergunta. Experimente. Qualquer dúvida, pode me chamar que corrijo pra você.

Comment: Entendi Obrigado

Comment: Alguém já tive esse problema.

Answer (score 0):

Se depois da publicação está dando Page not found. Pode ser o caminho da requisição que você está usando.
Tente montar a url assim:

```
        var strUrl = '@Url.Action("ConsultarRegiosPorPrestador", "TabelaFrete")';

    $.ajax({
        url: strUrl,
```

Comment: view de create:

Answer (score 0):

View create :

```
$(function () {

        $("#Ilha").change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/funcionario/Concelho/List/" + $("#Ilha > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                var items = "<option>--Selecione--</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, concelho) {
                    items += '<option value="' + concelho.Value + '">' + concelho.Text + '</option>';
                });
                $("#Concelho").html(items);
            });
        });
   });
```

no meu routeconfig criei Url:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
         "SelectConcelho",
         url: "funcionario/Concelho/List/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Soldado", action = "SelectConcelho", id = "" }
     );.....
```

e no controller fica o metodo

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult SelectConcelho(String id)
        {
            SITMSEntities conetContext = new SITMSEntities();
            int ids;
            List<SelectListItem> ConcelhoNome = new List<SelectListItem>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                ids = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                List<Concelho> Concelhos = conetContext.Concelho.Where(s => s.Numero_ilha == ids).ToList();
                Concelhos.ForEach(s =>
                {
                    ConcelhoNome.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s.Nome, Value = s.Numero.ToString() });

                }
                    );

            }
            return Json(ConcelhoNome, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

Comment: Utilize o "@Url.Action" para formatar sua URL

Comment: Desculpe ai Url referente a view ou routeconfig

Comment: funcionou ficou assim: var strUrl = '@Url.Action("GetConcelho", "Funcionario")';     $("#Ilha").change(function () {
            $.getJSON(strUrl +'/'+ ......

Answer (score 0):

funcionou ficou assim:

```
var strUrl = '@Url.Action("GetConcelho", "Funcionario")';  


 $("#Ilha").change(function () {
        $.getJSON(strUrl +'/'+ ......
```